# How to create a confusion matrix in python for a model implemented in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, confusion-matrix

I'm training a model in Python with TensorFlow, but I want to print a confusion matrix of the model predicted data (predicted vs actual). How can I do this? My code so far (excluding data load and preprocessing) is below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
Y = data.label
le = LabelEncoder()

Y = le.fit_transform(Y)


Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)

len(X)

sequences = list()
for line in X:
    # integer encode line
    encoded_seq = [char_index[char] for char in line]
    # store
    sequences.append(encoded_seq)



padded_inputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    sequences, padding="pre")
print(padded_inputs)


ex = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequences, padding="pre")
print(ex)


#And here is the train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(padded_inputs, Y, test_size= 0.1, 
random_state = 0)

X_train

y_train = y_train.astype("int32")

y_train

X_train.shape

X_test

print(X_train.shape)
max_len = 19
max_words = 57

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

def RNN():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(name='inputs',shape=[max_len])
    layer = Embedding(max_words,19,input_length=max_len)(inputs)
    layer = LSTM(64)(layer)
    layer = Dense(256,name='FC1')(layer)
    layer = Activation('relu')(layer)
    layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)
    layer = Dense(1,name='out_layer')(layer)
    layer = Activation('sigmoid')(layer)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=layer)
    return model

model = RNN()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(),metrics=['accuracy'])

num_epochs = 40
log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train,batch_size=128, epochs= num_epochs, validation_split=0.2, 
callbacks=[tensorboard_callback], verbose=2)



accr = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)


print('Test set\nLoss: {:0.3f}\nAccuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0],accr[1]))

yhat = model.predict(X_test)
```

I've tried the use: tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels, predictions, num_classes=None, weights=None, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32,name=None, but I don't know how to use it properly in this code.

Comment: whats the problem with `tf.math.confusion_matrix`?

Comment: where I need to enter the matrix with the labels should  I use X_train or y_train? for the predictions shall I use or X_test or y_test?

Comment: `tf.math.confusion_matrix(
    labels, predictions`, where `labels` -1-D Tensor of real labels for the classification task, `predictions` - 1-D Tensor of predictions for a given classification. in your case it is `tf.math.confusion_matrix(y_test, yhat)`

Comment: Thanks for that, but still did not work. I think I'm not filling the arguments (labels and predictions) with the correct variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since your model is outputting probabilities (as indicated by the final sigmoid activation function), you will first need to convert these probabilities to binary labels (0 or 1). You can use a threshold of 0.5 to classify everything above this threshold as 1, and everything below as 0.

Once you have the binary predictions, you can use tf.math.confusion_matrix to compare them with the actual labels.

Here is a short example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

yhat = model.predict(X_test)
yhat_binary = (yhat > 0.5).astype("int32")
conf_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(y_test.reshape(-1), 
yhat_binary.reshape(-1))
```

The tf.math.confusion_matrix function then compares these predictions (yhat_binary) with the true labels (y_test). Note that you need to reshape y_test and yhat_binary to 1D arrays since tf.math.confusion_matrix expects flat arrays!